# Calculating a rampdown interval

Tags: algorithms

I have an application that attempts to deliver a message to a client. It often fails on the first try so we currently retry it x number of times over a 2 day period. what I need to determine is a good formula for these retries that allows us to increase the interval between each retry over a max number of retries equal to 50 that spans approximately 3 days. Being admittedly a weak mathametician, the best I have come-up with is something like (number of retries)^2.5.

Comment: What constitutes a "good" formula? What's wrong with slightly less than two hours between any two attempts?

Comment: Sorry, not nearly enough detail. We would like to retry more often early-on and decrease the frequency over time.

Comment: Real world considerations are primary, you may not want to try to contact someone at 2:00 am. One could let the time interval between retries be an arithmetic progression, first retry at $a$ after first call, next $a+d$, and so on up to  $a+49d$. Decide what ratio of late gaps to early gaps should be, say $4$ to $1$. That gives $a+49d=4a$, say $a=16d$. Then use sum of arithmetic progression to find $a$. Or else can use a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can look at it this way. You have a base interval, $a$, between calls. You want an ever increasing actual interval, so you can multiply the base by an increasing factor. You are constrained that the sum total between all intervals has to sum to about 3 days. If we consider that the interval increases by $x\%$ each time, we can consider the following process. The first **retry** will be $a$ after the initial call. The next will be $a(1+x)$, the third will be at $a(1+x)^2$, and so on. We can take advantage of the properties of a geometric sum:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n a(1+x)^i = a\frac{1-(1+x)^{n+1}}{1-(1+x)}
$$
In this case, $b$ is actually a factor $(1+x)$ where $x$ is the percent increase in delay over the previous interval. So we want:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{49} a(1+x)^i = a\frac{1-(1+x)^{50}}{-x} = 3\cdot24\cdot60\cdot60=259200
$$
The limit is $49$ since the term $i=0$ represents the *first* retry. With one equation and two unknowns we have an infinite number of solutions, so for convenience, let's set the base interval at $1$ minute. So now we wwant to solve:
$$
\frac{1-(1+x)^{50}}{-x} = 4320\\
(1+x)^50-4320x-1=0
$$
Using a numerical solver, I get $x \approx 0.136053$ which means that the first *retry* is $60$ seconds after the initial call, the next is about $68.16$ later and so on. Below is the table for all the retries, and the sum of the Interval column is 259200 seconds, or three days. Now mix and match as necessary for different total retries, total elapsed time, or base interval.

```
Retry   Interval
1   60
2   68.16318192
3   77.43698948
4   87.97252669
5   99.94145567
6   113.5387937
7   128.9860909
8   146.5350396
9   166.471576
10  189.1205387
11  214.8509614
12  244.0820861
13  277.290194
14  315.0163656
15  357.8752972
16  406.5653165
17  461.8797605
18  524.7199023
19  596.1096359
20  677.2121593
21  769.3489268
22  874.0211809
23  992.9344126
24  1128.02615
25  1281.497528
26  1455.849152
27  1653.921843
28  1878.942924
29  2134.578806
30  2424.994725
31  2754.922609
32  3129.738183
33  3555.548552
34  4039.291713
35  4588.849598
36  5213.176498
37  5922.444967
38  6728.211561
39  7643.605144
40  8683.540799
41  9864.962853
42  11207.12096
43  12731.88374
44  14464.09513
45  16431.97913
46  18667.59971
47  21207.38325
48  24092.71204
49  27370.59856
50  31094.45148
```